# Postgres: Create generate series to non existent dates for multiple categories

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table contains some event information which includes an `event_start_date` and `event_end_date`

| event_start_date | event_end_date | event_type | event_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-22 | 2021-09-23 | Event_A | R |
| 2021-09-24 | 2021-09-26 | Event_A | G |
| 2021-09-24 | 2021-09-26 | Event_B | R |
| 2021-09-27 | 2021-09-28 | Event_A | H |
| 2021-09-27 | 2021-09-30 | Event_B | V |
| 2021-09-27 | 2021-10-04 | Event_C | GH |
| 2021-09-29 | 2021-09-30 | Event_A | D |
| 2021-10-01 | 2021-10-03 | Event_A | B |
| 2021-10-01 | 2021-10-03 | Event_B | L |
| 2021-10-04 | 2021-09-06 | Event_A | S |
| 2021-10-04 | 2021-10-08 | Event_B | DA |
| 2021-10-05 | 2021-10-11 | Event_C | N |

for some analysis I need to put `event_start_date` and `event_start_date` into a single columns and create an `event_date` so for that I need to create some dates that not exist (between start and end data for a specific event_type and event_name)

The goal output is below;

| event_date | event_type | event_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-22 | Event_A | R |
| 2021-09-23 | Event_A | R |
| 2021-09-24 | Event_A | G |
| 2021-09-25 | Event_A | G |
| 2021-09-26 | Event_A | G |
| 2021-09-24 | Event_B | R |
| 2021-09-25 | Event_B | R |
| 2021-09-26 | Event_B | R |
| 2021-09-27 | Event_A | H |
| 2021-09-28 | Event_A | H |
| 2021-09-27 | Event_B | V |
| 2021-09-28 | Event_B | V |
| 2021-09-29 | Event_B | V |
| 2021-09-30 | Event_B | V |
| 2021-09-27 | Event_C | GH |
| 2021-09-28 | Event_C | GH |
| 2021-09-29 | Event_C | GH |
| 2021-09-30 | Event_C | GH |
| 2021-10-01 | Event_C | GH |
| 2021-10-02 | Event_C | GH |
| 2021-10-03 | Event_C | GH |
| 2021-10-04 | Event_C | GH |
| 2021-09-29 | Event_A | D |
| 2021-09-30 | Event_A | D |
| 2021-10-01 | Event_A | B |
| 2021-10-02 | Event_A | B |
| 2021-10-03 | Event_A | B |
| 2021-10-01 | Event_B | L |
| 2021-10-02 | Event_B | L |
| 2021-10-03 | Event_B | L |
| ... | ... | ... |

My problem is that the code below generates a missing dates and if I had a single event that would be OK but I am not sure how to do with if you have multiple events runs in a same day.

```
WITH
  created_dates AS (
                     SELECT
                       date(first_value(start_time) OVER (PARTITION BY event_type,event_name )::date +
                            row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY event_type ORDER BY start_time) * INTERVAL '1 day') AS dte
                     FROM
                       events
                     WHERE
                       start_time > (current_date - INTERVAL '15 Days')
                   )
SELECT
  dte
, event_start_date
, event_type
, event_name
FROM
  created_dates cd
  LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT
                date(start_time) AS event_start_date
              , event_type
              , event_name
              FROM
                events
              WHERE
                start_time > (current_date - INTERVAL '15 Days')
            ) e
            ON e.event_start_date = cd.dte
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue using `UNION ALL`

```
WITH
  created_dates AS (
                     generate_series(min(start_time), now(), INTERVAL '1 day')::date as dte
                     FROM
                       events
                   
                   )
, event AS (
             SELECT
               dte
             , event_start_date
             , event_type
             , event_name
             , first_value(event_type) OVER (PARTITION BY grp1) AS event_type_final
             , first_value(event_name) OVER (PARTITION BY grp2) AS event_name_final
             FROM
               (
                 SELECT
                   dte
                 , event_start_date
                 , event_type
                 , event_name
                 , sum(CASE
                         WHEN event_type IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                       END) OVER (ORDER BY dte) AS grp1
                 , sum(CASE
                         WHEN event_name IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                       END) OVER (ORDER BY dte) AS grp2
                 FROM
                   created_dates cd
                   LEFT JOIN (
                               SELECT
                                 date(start_time) AS event_start_date
                               , event_type
                               , event_name
                               FROM
                                 events
                               WHERE
                                   event_type = 'Event_A'
                             ) e
                             ON e.event_start_date = cd.dte
                 GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
               ) filter
           )
, event2 AS (
                 SELECT
                   dte
                 , event_start_date
                 , event_type
                 , event_name
                 , first_value(event_type) OVER (PARTITION BY grp1) AS event_type_final
                 , first_value(event_name) OVER (PARTITION BY grp2) AS event_name_final
                 FROM
                   (
                     SELECT
                       dte
                     , event_start_date
                     , event_type
                     , event_name
                     , sum(CASE
                             WHEN event_type IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                           END) OVER (ORDER BY dte) AS grp1
                     , sum(CASE
                             WHEN event_name IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                           END) OVER (ORDER BY dte) AS grp2
                     FROM
                       created_dates cd
                       LEFT JOIN (
                                   SELECT
                                     date(start_time) AS event_start_date
                                   , event_type
                                   , event_name
                                   FROM
                                     pcubed_events
                                   WHERE
                                      event_type = 'Event_B'
                                 ) e2
                                 ON e2.event_start_date = cd.dte
                     GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
                   ) filter2
               )
, event3 AS (
                  SELECT
                    dte
                  , event_start_date
                  , event_type
                  , event_name
                  , first_value(event_type) OVER (PARTITION BY grp1) AS event_type_final
                  , first_value(event_name) OVER (PARTITION BY grp2) AS event_name_final
                  FROM
                    (
                      SELECT
                        dte
                      , event_start_date
                      , event_type
                      , event_name
                      , sum(CASE
                              WHEN event_type IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                            END) OVER (ORDER BY dte) AS grp1
                      , sum(CASE
                              WHEN event_name IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                            END) OVER (ORDER BY dte) AS grp2
                      FROM
                        created_dates cd
                        LEFT JOIN (
                                    SELECT
                                      date(start_time) AS event_start_date
                                    , event_type
                                    , event_name
                                    FROM
                                      events
                                    WHERE
                                        event_type = 'Event_C'
                                  ) e3
                                  ON e3.event_start_date = cd.dte
                      GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
                    ) filter3
                )
SELECT
  dte
, event_type_final
, event_name_final
FROM
  event
UNION ALL
SELECT
  dte
, event_type_final
, event_name_final
FROM
  event2
UNION ALL
SELECT
  dte
, event_type_final
, event_name_final
FROM
  event3
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've mis-understood your requirements, you've made this massively more complex than necessary.

You can simply "join" on to a function *(such as `generate_series()`)* using the keyword `LATERAL`.

```
SELECT
  events.event_id,
  linear_date_series.event_date
FROM
  events
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
  generate_series(
    events.event_start_date,
    events.event_end_date,
    INTERVAL '1 day'
  )
    AS linear_date_series(event_date)
```

Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=befc976afce54859a8edad68403b1645